# Amazon Redshift gets only 1 row from JSON with COPY command

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, copy, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to copy into Redshift JSON file with GA data with the following structure:

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:date",
          "ga:country"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:users",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:newUsers",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "name": "ga:sessionduration",
              "type": "TIME"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "20200731",
              "(not set)"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "7",
                  "6",
                  "5.0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "20200731",
              "Albania"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "2",
                  "1",
                  "0.0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "20200731",
              "Algeria"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1",
                  "1",
                  "224.0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
```

If I use the following JSON path, it only loads the first object in the array:

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
       "$['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][0]['dimensions'][0]",
       "$['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][0]['dimensions'][1]",
       "$['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][0]['metrics'][0]['values'][0]" ,
       "$['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][0]['metrics'][0]['values'][1]" ,
       "$['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][0]['metrics'][0]['values'][2]" 
    ]
}
```

I tried to change ['rows'][0] to ['rows'][*] and ['rows'] but nothing helped.
How should I change JSON paths to load all data from the file?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your SQL attempt.

Comment: copy dev.google_analytics.ga_country_test
from 's3://mbit-warehouse/TransferGANonBounceSessionsDataFromGaToS3/f33d58b1960c20d5bf84fc2ee4ae031a-2020-08-04T10:24:776'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/XXXXX'
JSON  's3://mbit-warehouse/TransferGANonBounceSessionsDataFromGaToS3/testfirst_copy.json'
DATEFORMAT 'YYYYMMDD'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift is only seeing the first row because of the index you specified `[0]` (the first item). You cannot *currently* directly ingest JSON that is nested like this.

To access all of the nested arrays in this file you will need to define it as an external table and then use the nested data query syntax.

Start here: ["Tutorial: Querying nested data with Amazon Redshift Spectrum"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-query-nested-data.html)